# Refresh JSON table in iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I have a table view, which is populated by a single tableviewcell that gets repeated, but filled with detail from a JSON file on the web. SO I have, on startup, 15 cells, each with its own JSON detail view. I'm wondering how I implement a refresh system, with a button preferably, that gets the app to re-download the JSON file. That way, if I make a change in the database, it can then be updated manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you already have a function to download the JSON and use it to render your table?

Create a button that calls that function, and after it returns reload the UITableView by calling reloadData on the UITableView.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have done that, but it doesn't let me call the function that gets the JSON file.

Comment: The bit where you call the function that should reload your table and that function itself would be a good start :)

Comment: I think this is what you mean...
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    CGRect frame;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768.0, 1024.0);
    }
    else
    {
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 368);
    }
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self loadStudents];
}`

Comment: The loadStudents is what loads the data. This is the stuff for loadStudents:
`-(void)loadStudents;
{
    NSString *url = @"http://apps.isaacn.me/sc/json.php?t=Students";
    Json *myJsonParser = [[Json alloc] init];
    [myJsonParser startLoadingObjectWithUrl:url andDelegate:self]; 
}